# Youtube Javascript API - How do you load an empty Video using swfobject()

Tags: youtube-api

I have a swfobject below, that gets loaded in $(ocument).onready etc...

swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/ma9I9VBKPiw?border=0&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer", "DivYoutubeEntertainmentContainer", "464", "320", "8", null, null, params, atts);

But when i want the page to load, i dont want the movie to be instantiated on page load.

Is there any way i can do this?

Comment: Why would you use swfobject? Google recommends using the iFrame API instead.

Comment: Nevermind, I see this was asked in '11 :)  The edit made it pop up in my question list.